# Its printing "No valid datasets were created." What can be the error in this code?

Tags: python, csv

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np
import os

csv_dir = r"C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\CSVModel\preparing_dataset\Seperated\Airline\csvs"


datasets = []


column_mapping = {
    "Bar Chart_1": ["Nationality", "First Name"],
    "Bar Chart_2": ["Country Name", "Flight Status"],
    "Line Chart_1": ["Name", "Departure data"],
    "Pie Chart_1": ["Flight Status"],
    "Pie Chart_2": ["Continents", "First Name"],
    "Stacked Bar Chart_1": ["Continents", "Gender"]
}


for filename in os.listdir(csv_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        file_path = os.path.join(csv_dir, filename)

        
        chart_type = filename.split("_")[1]  # Assumes the pattern "Airline_ChartType_1.csv"

        
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

        
        column_names = data.columns.tolist()
        print(f"Processing file: {filename}, Chart Type: {chart_type}")
        print(f"Column Names: {column_names}")

        
        columns_to_use = column_mapping.get(chart_type, [])  
        features = data[columns_to_use]

        if not features.empty:
            min_rows = features.shape[0]
            dataset = pd.DataFrame({'DatasetID': range(1, min_rows + 1),
                                    'Features': [list(row) for row in features.to_numpy()],
                                    'GraphType': [chart_type] * min_rows})

            
            datasets.append(dataset)


if datasets:
    
    final_dataset = pd.concat(datasets, ignore_index=True)

    
    print(final_dataset)
else:
    print("No valid datasets were created.")
```

My "columns_to_use" variable is empty even though i have crossed checked the name of my columns and the csv files

i want to extract various features from my different csv files. each csv file have different features for some reason its not reading my columns. When i read these files individually its working perfectly.
Please help me understand the problem

output i am getting:

```
Processing file: Airline_Bar Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Bar Chart
Column Names: ['Nationality', 'First Name']
Processing file: Airline_Bar Chart_2.csv, Chart Type: Bar Chart
Column Names: ['Country Name', 'Flight Status']
Processing file: Airline_Line Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Line Chart
Column Names: ['First Name', 'Departure Date']
Processing file: Airline_Pie Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Pie Chart
Column Names: ['Flight Status']
Processing file: Airline_Pie Chart_2.csv, Chart Type: Pie Chart
Column Names: ['Continents', 'First Name']
Processing file: Airline_Stacked Bar Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Stacked Bar Chart
Column Names: ['Continents', 'Gender']
No valid datasets were created.
```

Comment: Post full error, surely it tells you a line number where the error happens.

Comment: I have added the outptut

Comment: `datasets` only gets stuff appended to it if `not features.empty` so I assume that condition is never true?

Comment: Debug your code, print `features`, print `features.empty`, print `columns_to_use`, check if you're getting what you expect on the other variables.

Comment: did give it a try let me try further looking into
features.empty is true 
columns_to_use is [] (empty)

Comment: the problem is in reading of files, trying to identify yes the datasets wont be true until it actually reads the columns which it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem.

```
Processing file: Airline_Bar Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Bar Chart
Column Names: ['Nationality', 'First Name']

Processing file: Airline_Bar Chart_2.csv, Chart Type: Bar Chart
Column Names: ['Country Name', 'Flight Status']

Processing file: Airline_Line Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Line Chart
Column Names: ['First Name', 'Departure Date']

Processing file: Airline_Pie Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Pie Chart
Column Names: ['Flight Status']

Processing file: Airline_Pie Chart_2.csv, Chart Type: Pie Chart
Column Names: ['Continents', 'First Name']

Processing file: Airline_Stacked Bar Chart_1.csv, Chart Type: Stacked Bar Chart
Column Names: ['Continents', 'Gender']
```

If the `chart_type`, according to your output, has no `_1` or `_2`, when you do `columns_to_use = column_mapping.get(chart_type, [])` it always defaults to `[]`

You should `chart_type = filename.split("_", 1)[1]` to split only on the first `_`.

Right now from `Airline_ChartType_1` you get `['Airline', 'ChartType', '1']`

You want from `Airline_ChartType_1` to get `['Airline', 'ChartType_1']`